# Primefaces : Concatenar nombre del archivo con fecha actual en DataExporter

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable, xhtml

Soy junior en el framework Primefaces. Revisando la documentación oficial para realizar un desarrollo, encontré la forma de poder exportar un DataTable en diferentes formatos con DataExporter. Pero tras ver el código de ejemplo, me surge la pregunta :
¿se puede concatenar o asignar un string en filename que contenga el nombre, fecha y hora actual?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He investigado pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar comunidad, gracias.